# vuejs-router and bootstrap 5 modal dismiss not working together

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vuejs router on a modal. I want to close the modal when clicked on this router-link.

> ```
> <div class="modal" id="setting">
>   <div class="modal-dialog">
>     <div class="modal-content">
>       <div class="modal-body">
>         <router-link to="/blog" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Blog</router-link>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

When I click on 'Blog' the modal get closed but the page does not navigate to 'blog'. How can I solve thiis problem?
NB: In bootstrap 4 its working perfectly but in bootstrap 5 it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an on-click listener on Blog button which will be responsible of navigating to /blog page, the code will be like that :
1 - Replace router-link by a button :

```html
<div class="modal" id="setting">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button v-on:click="navigateToBlogPage" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Blog
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 - Add navigateToBlogPage method :

```js
....
methods : {
   navigateToBlogPage(){
       this.$router.push('/blog')
   }
}
....
```